# Netty setUnsignedByte function

Tags: netty

I am using Netty and the `ByteBuff` class, this class contains `getUnsignedByte` method that return unsigned byte, did there is set unsigned byte method?

If not, how can I set unsigned byte into `ByteBuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
short mybyte = value & 0xFF;
```

However note that bytes are between -128 / 127, so `mybyte` shall be a `short` (smallest int) in your code.

But within Netty you can safely write a signed byte (so using standard `byte` too in your code), and later on using `readUnsignedByte` ... That's why there is no `writeUnsignedByte` in Netty but simply `writeByte`.

Comment: Thank You. You use the methods `readUnsignedByte` and `writeByte`, what is the difference between these two methods and `setData` and `getUnsignedByte` methods?

Comment: I'm not sure to get your question. `readUnsignedByte` read one byte, returning it as an unsigned byte (cast to short) and move the `readerIndex` of +1. `writeByte` write one byte, moving the `writerIndex` of +1. `getUnsignedByte(position)` read one unsigned byte (still as a short) at the position given in argument. `setByte(position, byte)` is the reverse, writing one byte at the given position.